# JsonSlurper throws GroovyCastException when parsing text

Tags: groovy

I have the following code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"name":"John Doe"}')
```

but every time I run it I get:

```
Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '{name=John Doe}' with class 'groovy.json.internal.LazyMap' to class 'groovy.json.JsonSlurper' due to: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MissingPropertyExceptionNoStack: No such property: name for class: groovy.json.JsonSlurper
Possible solutions: type
```

The exception message isn't very clear to me, and I don't know why it's even getting thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After `parseText` invocation You're not receiving `JsonSluper` but `Map` instance. Here's how it works:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText('{"name":"John Doe"}')
assert slurper instanceof Map
```

Comment: I'm having a big "d'oh!" moment here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're using it incorrectly. This is the right way

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def result = slurper.parseText('{"name":"John Doe"}')
assert result instanceof Map
```